# Nix & Haskell - using default.nix from cabal2nix and a generic shell.nix

Tags: haskell, nix

From a pretty basic cabal file

```
cabal2nix ./. > default.nix
```

and then a shell.nix of

```
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  haskellPackages = pkgs.haskellPackages_ghc784.override {
    extension = self: super: {
      thispackage = self.callPackage ./default.nix {};
    };
  };
in pkgs.myEnvFun {
     name = haskellPackages.thispackage.name;
     buildInputs = [
       (haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (hs: ([
         hs.cabalInstall
       ] ++ hs.thispackage.propagatedNativeBuildInputs)))
     ];
   }
```

When in the nix-shell and running cabal configure it complains of missing packages such as text.

If I put the text package explicitly into the shell.nix such as

```
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  haskellPackages = pkgs.haskellPackages_ghc784.override {
    extension = self: super: {
      thispackage = self.callPackage ./default.nix {};
    };
  };
in pkgs.myEnvFun {
     name = haskellPackages.thispackage.name;
     buildInputs = [
       (haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (hs: ([
         hs.cabalInstall
         hs.text
       ] ++ hs.thispackage.propagatedNativeBuildInputs)))
     ];
   }
```

The cabal configure is fine, but I would expect hs.thispackage.propagatedNativeBuildInputs to be supplying these packages.

The very basic haskell project can be seen at

https://github.com/fatlazycat/haskell-nix-helloworld

Am I wrong in assuming you can work in this way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The `propagatedNativeBuildInputs` attribute is used by Haskell *libraries* to
propagate their build inputs down to other builds that depend on them. Your
package, however, is not a library --- it's an executable ---, so there's no
need to propagate the build inputs and thus `propagatedNativeBuildInputs` is
empty. Instead, you'll find the information you need in
`hs.thispackage.extraBuildInputs`.

Generally speaking, the definition of these kind of `nix-shell` environments
has become a lot easier in the release-15.09 branch (or nixos-unstable),
though. Simply run `cabal2nix --shell . >shell.nix` and you get a `shell.nix`
file that you can use for building with `nix-build shell.nix` as well as for
entering an interactive development environment with `nix-shell`.

http://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#users-guide-to-the-haskell-infrastructure has
a lot more information about the subject.